# Identifying the tenant that a user belongs to in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I created an ASP.NET web form app with authentication mechanism set to "Organizational Accounts" with the "Cloud - Multiple Organizations" option selected.

Running the default site I then "signed-up" two entirely unrelated Windows Azure AD accounts.

And I can see two entries in the default "Tenants" table.

So far.  So good.

However I cannot work out how to identify which tenant any of my signed in users maps to.

How do I map:
    *Context.User.Identity.Name*

To an individual tenant ID so that I can segregate data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just get the TenantId (http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid) or the IdentityProvider Claim (http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider). These are the claims that uniquely identify the Tenant of your user.
And looking at the claims has never been easier (since .NET 4.0). Here is a sample MVC razor view sample:

```
@foreach (var claim in ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims)
{
    <p><b>@claim.Type:</b> @claim.Value</p>
}
```

To ease this, you can create an extension method:

```
public static class ClaimsIdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetTenantId(this ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var claim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider"));
        return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : "unknown";
    }
}
```